# How to move SpriteNode by its angle?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games, skaction

I am trying to create a small game where SpriteNode (aka Player) moves up vertically on constant speed. I want to use its angle for steering left or right. However, I am not able to move the Player properly using its angle.

Thank you for your time.

Here is the partial code I wrote:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
        if location.x < self.size.width / 2 && location.y < self.size.height / 2 {
            // Turn Left
            print("TURNING LEFT")
            turn(left: true)
         } else if location.x >= self.size.width / 2 && location.y < self.size.height / 2 {
            // Turn Right
            print("TURNING RIGHT")
            turn(left: false)
         } else if location.y > self.size.height / 2 {
            // Go Up
            print("GOING UP!")
            move()
         }
    }
}

func turn(left: Bool) {
    if left {
        // Turn Left
        let turnAction = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 0.1, duration: 0.05)
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(turnAction)
        player?.run(repeatAction)
    } else {
        // Turn Right
        let turnAction = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -0.1, duration: 0.05)
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(turnAction)
        player?.run(repeatAction)
    }
}

func move() {
    // Move Up
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 15, duration: 0.5)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
    player?.run(repeatAction)
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

Using Trigonometry you can determine the sprite's x and y speed  in either direction create an angle for the sprite to point towards.  A great article that sums up how to do this can be found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5504-trigonometry-for-game-programming-spritekit-and-swift-tutorial-part-1-2).

If you simply wish to literally rotate the sprite it can be done by creating an SKAction for the rotation and running the action on the node.

```
// Create an action, duration can be changed from 0 so the user can see a smooth transition otherwise change will be instant.
SKAction *rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle: M_PI/4.0 duration:0]; 
//Simply run the action.
[myNode runAction: rotation];
```

Comment: Thank you for the article you direct me. I figured how to apply trigonometric calculation to solve my question. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @makertech81 link, I was able to write below code which works:

```
func move() {
    // Move Up
    let playerXPos = sin((player?.zRotation)!) * -playerSpeed
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: playerXPos, y: playerSpeed, duration: 0.5)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
    player?.run(repeatAction)
}
```

Basically, because I know the angle through `zRotation` and also I know how much Player will move toward Y, I was able to calculate its `sin` (which is X value). Therefore, moveAction will be properly calculated toward its destination.

Hope it helps.